# Don't yank character with <DEL> key in normal mode

Tags: cut-copy-paste, neovim, normal-mode

I am using `NeoVim` with `Tmux` on an Ubuntu on Windows setup. I have bound neovim's clipboard to the system clipboard by using : `set clipboard+=unnamedplus` and further configuration inside tmux.

So far, everything works just fine, except for a detail that bothers me.

As of now, when I delete a character in insert mode with <kbd>DEL</kbd>, it works just fine. However, when I do that in normal mode, the character is deleted but also copied to the clipboard.

Why is there this difference ? Is there a way to disable this behaviour ?

**NOTE:** I've also tried this on a Xubuntu machine running the same tmux config and `vim.gtk`, and I have the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick fix I can think of is remapping the del key so it will use _ register.
so if you just add 
`nnoremap <Del> "_x`
into your `$MYVIMRC` `init.nvim` for neovim or `~/.vimrc` for standard vim
it should just do what you ask

Comment: while this solution keeps my registry alone, it also moves my cursor 1 character to the right. Is there a way to avoid this and keep the current position ?

Comment: @Aserre can you please describe what do you mean it moves cursor to the right ?

Comment: Because for me it seems its just replacing the deleted character would you like to move the cursor left afterwards ? @Aserre

Comment: it moves the cursor to the right at the moment, i.e. if you have `DEMOTEXT` and the cursor is under `D`, pressing DEL will show `EMOTEXT`, but cursor will be under `M` instead of `E` (which is the insert mode behaviour : cursor doesn't move, only text does)

Comment: @Aserre i will update my answer shortly and if it fixes your issue please accept the answer

Comment: Are you sure you dont have any extra line in your vimrc responsible for this because i really cannot duplicate it so instead of updating my answer i will write here fix for your case just add <Left> after "_x
so it will look like
`nnoremap <Del> "_x<Left>`  @Aserre

Comment: Well, adding the `<Left>` does the trick for me. Thanks !

Comment: You are welcome but still i have no clue why it moves to right for me it doesnt do that

Answer (score 4):

This is because `<del>` is equivalent to <kbd>x</kbd>, or <kbd>dl</kbd>, which not only delete, but also yank to the unnamed register by default. From `:h <del>`

```
["x]<Del>   or                  *<Del>* *x* *dl*
["x]x           Delete [count] characters under and after the cursor
            [into register x] (not |linewise|).  Does the same as
            "dl".
            The <Del> key does not take a [count].  Instead, it
            deletes the last character of the count.
            See |:fixdel| if the <Del> key does not do what you
            want.  See |'whichwrap'| for deleting a line break
            (join lines).  {Vi does not support <Del>}
```

The fix is really simple. Just add

```
nnoremap <del> "_x
```

to your `.vimrc` file. This will make it delete into the black-hole register (like `/dev/null` on linux) and leave your other registers the same.

Comment: while this solution keeps my registry alone, it also moves my cursor 1 character to the right. Is there a way to avoid this and keep the current position ?